# copy table and drop it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I know we can simply create a new table and copy the old table by doing

```
select * into tbl2 from tbl1
```

i would like to check if table tbl2 exists, if it does then copy all the rows, if it doesn't then create a new one without having to specify the column names in tbl2 since I'm copying all the columns from tbl2 in tbl1. then, I would like to drop old table(tbl1)

```
if not exists(select * from tbl1 where id = 1)
   create table tbl2()
   drop tbl1
go
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2'))
BEGIN
    -- tbl2 exists, so just copy rows
    INSERT INTO tbl2 SELECT * FROM tbl1;
END
ELSE BEGIN
    -- tbl2 doesn't exist, so create new table tbl2 and copy rows 
    SELECT * INTO tbl2 FROM tbl1;
    DROP tbl1;
END
```

This won't copy indexes, keys, etc though - just the column names on create (in the else branch).

Answer (score 0):

```
If object_id ("tempdb..#tbl2") is null
    Select * into #tbl2 from tbl1
Else
    Insert #tbl2 select * from tbl1
```

If you don't  want it to be temp table get rid of #  and tempdb

Answer (score 0):

This will check for tbl2, if it does exist, insert into table 2. If it does not exist, it will select into tbl2.

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2'))
BEGIN
    -- If the table exists, insert into:
    INSERT INTO tbl2 SELECT * from tbl1
    drop tbl1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO tbl2 FROM tbl1
END
```

Comment: hi dan! it works when tbl2 doesn't exist but gives error if tbl2 already exist. I had to remove table_schema ='schema' part and worked fine. thanks.

Comment: Ah yeah, you would need to change schema to match the schema of tbl1. Having that part ensures it's looking at the correct table if the same table name exists under multiple schema,  schema.tbl1 vs sch.tbl1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if it does exists how could you know for sure that the table definition is exactly the same, if you do not want such additional check and always assume they are the same then you can use INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl2]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    -- create the table only if not there
    select * into tbl2 from tbl1 where 1 <> 1
END

insert into tbl2 select * from tbl1
```

Or you can change it to remove the 1<>1 to just insert record, and put the insert into in a else block.

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl2]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    -- create the table only if not there
    select * into tbl2 from tbl1
END
ELSE BEGIN
    insert into tbl2 select * from tbl1
END
```

The exists code block is what generated by Sql Server management studio and I just copied it.